# Is there an advertising network for firefox OS

Tags: networking, firefox-os

Does anybody know of an advertising network which supports Firefox os. I know AdSense would work because its HTML but im not sure if its allowed by their rules etc. Would it be allowed on hosted apps because they are websites?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a post on the Mozilla Hacks Blog that talks about one ad monetization option with Firefox OS:

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/10/monetization-with-inneractive-on-firefox-os/

Comment: Its helpful to summarize the important points from the link in the question text.

Answer (score 3):

All advertising networks that work in a web browser (specifically Firefox) should work on Firefox OS including Google Adsense.

For hosted and plain packaged apps this should be as simple including the integration code in your app but for privileged packaged apps this usually creates an issue with [CSP violations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Developing/Packaged_apps). To get around this you can create an `IFrame` and put the integration code in there.

Mozilla has a library for integrating ads using the Inneractive network as Mark Coggins already mentioned here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/10/monetization-with-inneractive-on-firefox-os/

One issue with Google Adsense ads is you cannot change the target of the ad so in an app context, clicking an ad means visiting the page inside the app instead of an external browser window. This is logged as an issue in this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=886605

Comment: You can ask AdSense support to enable new windows as target. Worked fine for me.